# System.InvalidOperationException: "Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer("C:/Users/heerm/Downloads/mixkit-positive-interface-beep-221.wav");
simpleSound.Play();
```

This code occures the in the title named error massage and I don´t know how to convert a wav-file into pcm wave files or how to play different fileformats with winforms. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If we want to play wav files in winform, we can use the following code:

```
using System.Media;
private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"Sound Path");
        soundPlayer.Play();
    }
```

This method can play wav files normally. If you still get the error “ Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files”, there are some problem with your sound file format like this:
[Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300185/sound-api-only-supports-playing-pcm-wave-files)

And this page can give you some suggestions on converting to pcm wave files.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d30a3002-a553-4bb2-b8da-058255395a5e/the-error-occured-when-i-tried-to-play-wav-file-winforms?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Link doesn't work and the response implies there is something wrong with his wave file - there is not potentially - there are multiple types of wave format.